# Google can not connect to the server?

Tags: 6

Google Webmaster's tool tells me on a site that "Request timed out or site is blocking Google". On that site. I am wondering how to fix this.

Probably relevant info: I'm using Varnish in front of nginx and also user use iptables and [DDoS deflate](http://deflate.medialayer.com/). The site is large but works pretty smoothly, with load less than 2 most of the times. The standard Pressflow 6 robots.txt is there and accessible through browser.

I am not quite sure how to figure out what blocks googlebots and how to fix the problem. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: Check for any disallow statements in [robots.txt](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings in the `nodewords` (or another meta tags) module look for `noindex`